# Why do I get a Runtime Error on PC, but SE works fine on my smartphone and iPad

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

I now try to visit the [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/) of SO, but I get the following error:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ### *Runtime Error*
>
> **Description:** An exception occurred while processing your
>   request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the
>   custom error page for the first exception. The request has been
>   terminated.

But I can visit it using my smartphone and iPad, all are using the same wifi.

I use Chrome 24.0.1312.57. And I already cleared my cache including all of the items, and tried with different browsers(Safari 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)).

The request look like below:

[image]

I also tried  **overridden** the User Agent with iPad-iOS 5, but still not works.

Does anybody know why? And how can I visit it normally?

Comment: No-repro. Tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @Bart I tried, I also tried another browser, but still unlucky.

Comment: Wasn't there somebody yesterday complaining about the same thing? There must be something to this

Comment: And what if you try some incognito mode? Clearing your cache might not have wiped the cookies and HTML5 Local Storage.

Comment: Indeed, [Site or browser issue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167649/site-or-browser-issue), @Pekka웃

Comment: To all, I update my post.

Comment: Any errors on [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help)?

Comment: @Arjan all are ok.

Comment: If you look at your request url you are requesting the error page. Can you include the requestheader and responseheaders if you just hit http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @rene it just redirect to this error page with a status code 302.

Comment: @Arjan It seems indeed be a DNS issue to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a DNS issue pointing to our Oregon data center we recently moved away from.  I've just closed our HAProxy backends out there so you'll see a nicer page rather than the app error you were seeing (due to us rebuilding those database servers at that point).

We can't really help from our side on this since the issue is local DNS, the best we can do is advise.  What DNS server are you pointed to?  Also, does this persist after a DNS resolver flush locally?

Comment: I had pointed to 69.59.197.21 before, after I remove this, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @pktangyue, did you set that value manually somewhere, or is some DNS server to blame? In case of the DNS server, then maybe it's nice to know which one.

Comment: @Arjan I set it local in my computer, and I really don't remember why I did this. :P