# Can't access any Stack Exchange site

Tags: support

For about a week now, I have been unable to access any Stack Exchange sites from my home network. Whenever I try, the browser tries to load for a while, then says it cannot connect. The only way I have been able to access the sites is via a proxy.

All packets are lost when I ping the server:

```
>ping stackoverflow.com

Pinging stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.16] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 198.252.206.16:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I believe this is perhaps something to do with the recent change of the data centre. I first thought that this was a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) issue, but it has been a week now (and I assume you have proxies in your old data centre). The only alternative I can think of is that my IP address is, for some reason, blacklisted.

Is this a known issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: Try a traceroute to see where it stops?

Comment: @J.Steen I get "1 2 ms 1 ms 1 ms 192.168.1.1" first, then all the remaining lines are "2 * * * Request timed out." I get a full list for any other domain.

Comment: Try clearing you DNS cache.

Comment: @Oded Stackoverflow.com resolves to `198.252.206.16` for me, too, though. It doesn't look like that's the old address? (There was one user with a DNS problem recently, but it doesn't seem to be the same thing: [Why do I get a Runtime Error on PC, but SE works fine on my smartphone and iPad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167818/168108#168108))

Comment: @Pekka웃 - You are right. I get the same IP resolution. Looks like an issue with the ISP of the OP.

Comment: and if you try a traceroute to stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net

Comment: A few others seem to being having this issue with my ISP (Virgin Media -- see [here](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Up-to-120Mb-Setup-Equipment/stackoverflow-com/td-p/1722156)). Hopefully they pick this issue up soon; I'll make a phone call tomorrow.

Comment: What is your source ip?

Comment: I just double checked, and your IP isn't blocked by any of our systems. So it is probably something wrong at your provider.

Comment: @Zypher there's another user with the same problem: [IP Banned on Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168980)

Comment: @Brendon: I am the other user having same problem. Are you by any chance Virgin Media customer in UK? Their boards seem to be littered with multiple reports of inability to reach stack exchange sites over the last week or so.

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash Yes I am a Virgin Media customer. There seems to be an issue routing IPs beginning 198 for some reason (e.g. lag.tv I've seen mentioned).

Answer (score 11):

We are contacting the virgin media NOC, hopefully we will be able to help expedite resolution of this for you guys.

As we get more info we will update this answer.

Comment: Any info from virgin? Not much from the support forums - just wait a few days.. [link](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Up-to-120Mb-Setup-Equipment/stackoverflow-com/td-p/1722156/page/8)

Comment: I'm hopeful that this can be worked out. I really miss Arqade and SO at home!