# IP Banned on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, ban, ip-ban

I am a regular Stack Overflow user who does not spam, usually posts OK questions etc. However, for two weeks now my IP appears to be banned from any Stack website. I can easily get to the site via proxy, but it's a bit annoying to have to do it every time I want to read some answers etc.

Question is — who do I ask why I got banned and how to get an unban as

1. I believe it's not deserved (unless I did something wrong not knowing about it),
2. Perhaps my security is compromised and someone is doing something nasty using my IP as a cover.

Comment: So you are saying you cannot browse the site at all when you visit without going through a proxy?

Comment: Hi psubsee2003, yes. Blank. When I try to ping it times out. Looks to me like iptables drop or something similar. Otherwise account seems to be working (when used via proxy). Although I did not try creating questions recently.

Comment: @Bart, well unless I am mistaken, 'IP ban' (at least on the firewall level) does not let you establish communication with the server at all and this is what I feel is happening.

Comment: Could it be that you have a faulty DNS setting? There was a server move recently. What do you get when `ping`ing `stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: @Pekka웃: nada - Pinging 198.252.206.16. Request timed out. 100% loss. (When I ping from different IP I got same IP for stackoverflow but my packets go through)

Comment: Strange. This person has the same problem: [Can't access any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168764)

Comment: @Pekka웃: Actually now I see that multiple VirginMedia customers have the same problem for the last week or so...

Comment: Confirmed? See [Some Virgin Media users having issues accessing Stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170927/some-virgin-media-users-having-issues-accessing-stackoverflow-com).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Email us at `team@stackexchange.com`. Include your IP address as reported by http://whatsmyip.org and we'll check things out.

Comment: @anna Just to confirm my understanding, if a user were banned at the IP level, would this prevent the user from visiting the site altogether or just from participating?

Comment: @Bart Yeah, we just drop the connection when someone comes in from a banned IP.

Comment: Could you explain, how you rule out a proxy serving multiple users? My university enforces a transparent proxy, so a few hundred users are behind one ip address. Banning on the IP-level seems quite harsh and not very errorprone.

Comment: @Lars We don't. But we are very hesitant to hand out permanent IP bans basically for the reasons you describe.