# Logged in from another IP and now I'm banned

Tags: support, post-ban

I was at a coffee shop, and logged onto my stackoverflow account to post a question, when I got the Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

I checked out the thread and it doesn't tell you how to resolve this question.

I logged back in at home, and now it gives me this here too! What happened? I'm supposed to be in good standing, at least that's what I thought.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Potentially Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172440/why-is-the-ip-ban-administered-and-how-is-it-carried-out

Comment: It's not because you logged on from a different IP, it's because of your question quality. Given your one downvoted question, one upvoted, and several at zero, I'd bet you have at least a couple deleted questions.

Comment: FYI: I access the site from a minimum of 3 IPs a day plus the number of IPs that my phone uses as I commute around town and I have never had a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question ban goes to a lower level than just your account. The question ban goes down to the IP address

As quoted from here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

> Since the ban is based on IP address as well, when you browse from a shared computer or from work location that give the same IP address to many end users it's enough that one get banned and all others are "banned" as well. To rectify this, just browse from a different location.

So it may not be your account, simply the computer you are browsing from.

Also, the question bans take a while to put into place. You might not have had any action on your questions in a while, and you suddenly get that message. This is because the check for banning users does not run around the clock

Comment: I see... I e-mailed the stack-overflow team, hopefully I can get this resolved. Don't really have the option to go from another location. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no script banning users. The question block is a check that runs when someone attempts to ask a question and it takes into account the current state of their questions. The exact formula is not revealed for obvious reasons, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 20):

No one person banned you. There's a super-secret algorithm in place that automatically post-bans users that **continually** post bad content.  You were caught by this algorithm.

How were your questions deemed bad? downvotes (or a lack of votes), closure, deletion.  As other users have stated, [you should follow the directions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) in order to work towards being unbanned.

Here are specific problems I see with your questions that would keep me from upvoting them:

- [Website Mortgage Calculator = JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916256/website-mortgage-insurance-calculator-javascript): This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It asks what technology to use to build a specific thing.  Imagine for a second you're a random internet user, stumbling onto the site through Google.  Can you imagine the answer to this question being useful to anyone other than yourself?  Or if it is, can you imagine anyone having the specific set of criteria you have for this? Probably not.
- [Java While and If Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937353/java-while-and-if-and-else): This question seems a bit too localized for Stack Overflow. You're seeing a specific debugging problem with a specific set of code (99 bottles of beer), and you want someone to help you fix it.  That's all well and good, except that once again, the answer to this particular question isn't useful to anyone else.  It feels like you wanted to have live debugging help for a really basic problem.  This is one of those times where you should bite the bullet and try things. If you don't understand how something works, read up on it, but this question can never really be useful to anyone else.
- [Java Variable Holder and its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030311/java-variable-holder-and-its-value): Read above. Same issue. Debug more, read code, read more. Not a good fit for a knowledge site.
- [Java Codingbat code should work but doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271876/java-codingbat-code-should-work-but-doesnt): See above.
- [Finding larger number within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367651/finding-larger-number-within-a-range): A little more interesting; with appropriate editing, this could be a truth table question.  But again, it is looking for specific debugging help on a specific issue that doesn't have a general audience
- [performing a for loop on a retrieved array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414379/performing-a-for-loop-on-a-retrieved-array): Same thing again. "I need debugging help. I should go to Stack Overflow."

I recognize that it's hard for you to hear this feedback, but without it, you'll likely get unbanned by the system but re-banned after you ask another question.

Stack Overflow **is not a help forum**. It's a Q & A site. The process of helping you is incidental to the goal of having a site filled with good programming knowledge that is searchable by others.

Your questions all have something in common, they show that you should look into debugging.  It's a hard pill to swallow, but you have all the tools at your disposal to solve these problems. If you're not sure how to debug programs, I'd take a look at [Debug It!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193435628X), it's a great book about that very thing.  Learn to debug, and six of your questions would never has needed to be asked (and you wouldn't be in the mess you're in now).

I hope you get unbanned, but more than that, I hope you'll take this as a learning opportunity and focus on how to improve your questions so that they're more useful to other people.