# Is my public IP banned from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-completed, ip-address

At home, I cannot access stackoverflow.com or meta.stackoverflow.com at all; my browser gets a `The connection has timed out` error.

All other Stack Exchange sites are fine. Accessing them from work is fine.

Both `ping` and `tracert` work just fine. I disabled both my router and PC firewalls, and flushed my DNS cache, but no dice.

My public facing IP is **75.119.247.95**.

Is my IP being blocked on Stack Overflow's end, or should I contact my ISP?

Comment: I don’t think Stack Exchange blocks anyone at the IP level. The worst they’d do as far as IP blocking goes would be making the site read-only for a certain IP address. I’m not sure why you would be having connectivity trouble; you might need to contact your ISP, as you were considering.

Comment: I am assuming you're having problem on ur PC/Laptop... Before contacting your ISP, try this... visit StackOverflow.com using Smartphone or Tablet which are connected to same Wi-Fi... If it works then ur PC/Laptop has problem.

Comment: Can confirm it does not work on my phone either

Comment: If its blocked, then how is this posted?

Comment: @UniKitty *All other Stackexchange sites are fine*

Comment: Then you might  want to use the "contact us" link below

Comment: @UniKitty No, not really given the answer of Tim

Comment: @UniKitty That form _might_ not be working  properly for them, though it is the ideal way to contact us about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IP Banned on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168980/ip-banned-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate as the target has concrete actions one can take if they want to have their IP ban lifted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the IP ban administered and how is it carried out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172440/why-is-the-ip-ban-administered-and-how-is-it-carried-out)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We do not *outright* block IPs for spamming and bad behavior, we simply prevent accounts coming from them that aren't very established from posting. In order to get an outright block, something from your IP has to be hitting us really hard with abusive requests.

Turns out, that's what happened back on March 28, 2011 - when about 39,000 bogus requests per second started coming from it.

I've contacted our SRE team to look into dropping the rule because it is quite old, and there's *strong* evidence that a real person is now using it. Hang tight, might take a while.

**Update**

Done.

Comment: That did it. Now I can finally go back to flogging my male enhancement pills.

Comment: Hey. Can you check for me too? I am also facing similar issue

Comment: @Jdeep I don't work here any longer - you could try contacting the team using the contact link in the footer of any site.