# Why does this particular reopen review task incorrectly show with the old wording of the duplicate close reason?

Tags: support, review, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

[Prior to February 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux), the duplicate close reason notice used to have the following wording:

> This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.

This wording was removed in February 2013.

However, I came across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168980/ip-banned-on-stack-exchange) in the reopen review queue, and the reason box [shows that old wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/78308) to users who can review the item:

[image: Old description quoted above]

This doesn't seem like correct behavior, because:

- When questions closed as duplicates prior to the above change show up in the queue, I've always seen them have the newer wording in the reason box:

  > This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- Also, this question was closed in *March* 2013, *after* the changes linked above. The newer-style automatic duplicate notice, rather than the old Community user edit, shows the duplicate target.

Why does this specific question show an old close reason in the dialog?

It seems that it's because it's a newer-style closure but the reason ID is somehow 1, not 101. Why is that?

Comment: I currently see the current wording.

Comment: @Luuklag The screenshot is from the review link.

Comment: It shows the current wording in the question itself but the old wording in the review queue. I noticed this too earlier today.

Comment: Related: [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would have used the words "reopen review task" in place of "question" there, but ran into the title length limit.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxPHK.png

Comment: @Luuklag As you voted outside of the review queue, you can't review it. The phrase only shows up if you can review the item.

Comment: Also shown without the colon that usually separates the close reason from the description.