# Cannot access Stack Overflow; Requests time out

Tags: support

For a couple of days now, I have not been able to access Stack Overflow via my WiFi (though can through 3G, which is how I'm connected now).

It always just returns "Could not connect" no matter what browser or what device, and a traceroute did 30 hops and "Request timed out" for all of them : (

I haven't spammed, and although my reputation is low, I don't think I've had any negative responses. I'm just more of a reader than an active user, as I can solve most of my problems from reading other threads. Regardless, it seems the Stack Exchange network has blocked my IP. Is there a way of getting this reversed? : (

I'm 75% designer / 25% developer, so need SO frequently!!

Hope someone can help.

-Chris

Comment: Can you ping or tracerout to stackoverflow.com using your wifi?

Comment: Traceroute timed out on 30 hops… (I assume that means no?)

Comment: What IP are you getting on pings?

Comment: 198.252.206.16… : s

Comment: Well, that's the correct IP. Are you getting results from it? And at what point does the tracerout stop returning stuff (that is, what is the last address that it shows)?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it right; I'm on Windows for a start, so not sure I should call it Traceroute. I did a tracert in Command Prompt. It

Comment: …just attempted to connect to 198.252.206.12 thirty times, and said "Request timed out" each time.

Comment: Oh, sorry. 198.252.206.16. Last one was a typo.

Comment: If you are on a windows box, try `ipcofig /flushdns` in the command line

Comment: It has "Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache", but I still can't access the site(s) and tracert is still just timing out… :' (

Comment: Have you reset your wifi AP and your router?

Comment: Yep. The old 'turn it off, run it back on again' was the first thing I tried! : p.    Thank you for your help. As I say I'm more designer than developer, so these more technical issues stump me immediately.

Comment: @ChrisFox - This is something you may need to take up with your ISP.

Comment: Do other sites fail? Sister sites, like e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com? Can you connect to other web sites? Any funky firewall configuration on the machine or the WiFi router?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com delivering the same response, and the same IP address when I try to tracert it. Am I screwed then? No firewall changes should have happened in the last few days. None that I've manually implemented anyway…

Comment: @ChrisFox if you didn't know about it you can use a proxy server, I know its not a solution but it should allow you to workaround the problem. The IP Address you have is not new is it?

Comment: I thought the SE network blocks people using proxies because it's hacker-type behaviour? I read something similar to that trying to research my problem. The IP address isn't new as far as I'm aware. I have found a thread on my ISP's help forum that indicates lots of other people having the same issue, so the problem may indeed lie with them.  If I discover the problem, I'll post here in case it helps anyone else, but otherwise thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Are you with Virgin Media by any chance? [Can't access any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168764)

Comment: Anybody found a solution to this?