# Some Virgin Media users having issues accessing Stackoverflow.com

Tags: support

Hi I'm the community manager for Virgin Media's Help & Support forum, we've had a bunch of reports of our users having issues accessing Stackoverflow.com. The problem appears to be outside our network so we'd like to speak to one of your network people to try and see what's going wrong here. Could a Stack Exchange rep drop me an email at help.forum@virginmedia.co.uk and I can put you in touch with out network team.

Comment: You're probably likely to get a better response by contacting the Stack Exchange team using [the contact us form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) or by emailing team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: We recently had Virgin Media contact us about the problem; we're fully cooperating but we see nothing wrong on our end that would cause the issue.

Comment: @MarkWilkin for your reference, virgin ticket: F002365607

Comment: Cheers Peter just got your email, will make sure everyone's linked up and talking to each other on this one.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168764/cant-access-any-stack-exchange-site

Comment: It started to work today. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seem to be about an issue that is better handled by contacting the SE staff directly via E-Mail